# How to make a gently flashing button in jQuery and SASS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, sass

In my Rails app I will sometimes have to make certain buttons flash / pulsate.

These buttons vary in color. Some are red, others are green, and others again are blue.

This is my jQuery:

```
setInterval(function(){
  $('a.flashing').toggleClass('blink');
}, 1000);
```

And this is my CSS (SASS actually):

```
.blink {
  background-color: red;
}
```

This works.

However, I don't want all buttons to flash in red.

Instead, to make this effect a bit more gentle on the eyes, each button should flash in a slightly darker shade of its original color (which as you know may vary).

How can this be achieved with as little code as possible and ideally no jQuery plugins at all?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: As you can't alter the color, due to this affecting different types of buttons, why not affect the brightness (or saturation)? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter, unfortunately only for CSS3

.blink { filter: brightness(1.2) }

Comment: Thanks! This is actually what I ended up doing: `filter: brightness(1.1)`. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a SASS (+ Compass) function creating a pulsate effect. The number of pulsations can be specified via $count.

```
=keyframes($name)
  @-webkit-keyframes #{$name}
    @content

  @-moz-keyframes #{$name}
    @content

  @-ms-keyframes #{$name}
    @content

  @keyframes #{$name}
    @content

=animation-name($name)
  -webkit-animation-name: $name
  -moz-animation-name: $name
  -o-animation-name: $name
  animation-name: $name

=animation-duration($duration)
  -webkit-animation-duration: $duration
  -moz-animation-duration: $duration
  -o-animation-duration: $duration
  animation-duration: $duration

=animation-timing-function($timing-function)
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: $timing-function
  -moz-animation-timing-function: $timing-function
  -o-animation-timing-function: $timing-function
  animation-timing-function: $timing-function

=animation-iteration-count($iteration-count)
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: $iteration-count
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: $iteration-count
  -o-animation-iteration-count: $iteration-count
  animation-iteration-count: $iteration-count

=animation-direction($direction)
  -webkit-animation-direction: $direction
  -moz-animation-direction: $direction
  -o-animation-direction: $direction
  animation-direction: $direction

// define keyframes
+keyframes(change_background_color)
  to
    background-color: $some_color

// define the mixin
=pulsate($time:0.2s, $count:8)
  +animation-name(change_background_color)
  +animation-duration($time)
  +animation-iteration-count($count)
  +animation-direction(alternate)
  +animation-timing-function(ease-in-out)

// use the mixin in a class
.pulsate-8times
  +pulsate(1s, 16)
```

No need for JS (except for toggling the class). Set $count to 'infinite' for an endless pulsation.

JSFiddle with the compiled CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/3L2yA/

Update: same in SCSS (thanks to http://sasstoscss.com/ ;-):

```
@mixin keyframes($name) {
    @-webkit-keyframes #{$name} {
        @content;
    }

    @-moz-keyframes #{$name} {
        @content;
    }

    @-ms-keyframes #{$name} {
        @content;
    }

    @keyframes #{$name} {
        @content;
    }
}

@mixin animation-name($name) {
  -webkit-animation-name: $name;
     -moz-animation-name: $name;
       -o-animation-name: $name;
          animation-name: $name;
}

@mixin animation-duration($duration) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: $duration;
     -moz-animation-duration: $duration;
       -o-animation-duration: $duration;
          animation-duration: $duration;
}

@mixin animation-timing-function($timing-function) {
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: $timing-function;
     -moz-animation-timing-function: $timing-function;
       -o-animation-timing-function: $timing-function;
          animation-timing-function: $timing-function;
}

@mixin animation-iteration-count($iteration-count) {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: $iteration-count;
     -moz-animation-iteration-count: $iteration-count;
       -o-animation-iteration-count: $iteration-count;
          animation-iteration-count: $iteration-count;
}

@mixin animation-direction($direction) {
  -webkit-animation-direction: $direction;
     -moz-animation-direction: $direction;
       -o-animation-direction: $direction;
          animation-direction: $direction;
}

@include keyframes(change_background_color) {
  to {
    background-color: $some_color;
  }
}

@mixin pulsate($time: 0.2s, $count: 8) {
  @include animation-name(change_background_color);
  @include animation-duration($time);
  @include animation-iteration-count($count);
  @include animation-direction(alternate);
  @include animation-timing-function(ease-in-out);
}

.pulsate-8times {
  @include pulsate(1s, 16);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to convert this to my syntax here right now (it's `scss` instead of `sass` actually).

Comment: OK, thanks. This works. And even though I ended up with `eithed's` solution (because it's so incredibly simple), I will mark your answer as the correct one because I learned a lot from it.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a CSS3 transition effect, then you don't need to jump through and JS hoops. `.normal` is the default color.

```
 .normal {
      background-color:rgba(250,20,10,1);
      transition: all .5s ease;
    }

.blink {
      background-color:rgba(250,20,10,.2);
      transition: all .5s ease;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but to be honest, I couldn't get this to work. In fact I've been playing with `keyframes` etc. all day and gave up at some point because I couldn't get it to work with the large amount of different colors in my app.

Answer (score 0):

try animating the background color using jQuery

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div1" class="normal" >some text</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#div1").animate({backgroundColor: '#dd6666'}, 500);
}, 1000);
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TUdpD/2/)

Comment: Thanks but this is not for me because the color value is hardcoded and I need it to be more flexible.